# Consolidate sets of identifiers in one column into groups with unique identifiers from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, uniqueidentifier

I've spent more time on this problem than I care to admit. I have a solution (below) implementing cursors but I wonder if it's possible with other methods? To me, it was especially difficult because there aren't the usual constructs in SQL, such as arrays.

This also seems like a good problem for using recursion, but I couldn't figure that out. The platform is MSSQL 2008 or T-SQL.

Consider a table which has two columns of non-unique identifiers, and a date column. For each date, I want to consolidate or group the identifiers in one column (X) into sets where the identifiers in the second column (Y) are unique.

- X identifiers are non-unique
- Y identifiers are unique within each set of X identifiers, but non-unique overall
- When combining, the minimum possible X identifier is used
- An X identifier will not span more than a single date

Perhaps the best place to start is with some sample data. There is also some extended sample data in the solution. In the actual implementation in which I'm using this, there are typically less than 200 rows and most often will be less than 100.

```
Dt         X     Y     newX
6/1/2012   1     1     1
6/1/2012   1     2     1
6/1/2012   2     3     1
6/1/2012   3     1     3   <-- because Y=1 is already in X=1
6/1/2012   3     4     3
6/1/2012   4     5     1
6/1/2012   5     4     1   <-- Y=4 is in X=3 but not X=1
6/1/2012   5     6     1
6/1/2012   6     4     6   <-- Y=4 is in X=1 and X=3
6/1/2012   6     7     6
```

The solution...

```
-- task: combine/condense/reassign/coalesce/collapse/consolidate sets of X identifiers into groups with unique Y identifiers, and by date
--  - X identifiers are non-unique
--  - Y identifiers are unique within each set of X identifiers, but non-unique overall
--  - When combining, the minimum possible X identifier is used
--  - An X identifier will not span more than a single date

--drop table #tmpA

CREATE TABLE #tmpA (Dt DATETIME, X INT, Y INT, newX INT, origX INT)

-- sample data
--                        Dt                              X  Y  newX
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-01' AS DATETIME), 1, 2, 0, 1)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-01' AS DATETIME), 1, 1, 0, 1)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-01' AS DATETIME), 2, 5, 0, 2)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-01' AS DATETIME), 3, 2, 0, 3)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-01' AS DATETIME), 3, 3, 0, 3)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-01' AS DATETIME), 4, 3, 0, 4)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-01' AS DATETIME), 5, 5, 0, 5)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-01' AS DATETIME), 6, 5, 0, 6)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-01' AS DATETIME), 7, 2, 0, 7)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-01' AS DATETIME), 7, 1, 0, 7)       -- causes a debug 4

INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-02' AS DATETIME), 1, 2, 0, 1)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-02' AS DATETIME), 1, 1, 0, 1)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-02' AS DATETIME), 2, 5, 0, 2)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-02' AS DATETIME), 3, 2, 0, 3)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-02' AS DATETIME), 3, 3, 0, 3)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-02' AS DATETIME), 4, 3, 0, 4)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-02' AS DATETIME), 5, 5, 0, 5)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-02' AS DATETIME), 6, 5, 0, 6)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-02' AS DATETIME), 7, 7, 0, 7)
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-02' AS DATETIME), 7, 1, 0, 7)       -- causes a debug 3 if below not used
--INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-02' AS DATETIME), 7, 6, 0, 7)     -- causes a debug 8 if above not used
INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES (CAST('2012-06-02' AS DATETIME), 7, 5, 0, 7)

DECLARE @X          INT
DECLARE @tX         INT     -- temporary X
DECLARE @Y          INT
DECLARE @Dt         DATETIME
DECLARE @tDt        DATETIME = CAST('1900-01-01' AS DATETIME)   -- temporary date
DECLARE @newX       INT
DECLARE @min_X      INT     -- minimum X without Y duplicate
DECLARE @min_newX   INT

DECLARE CursorA CURSOR FOR SELECT Dt, X, Y, newX FROM #tmpA
ORDER BY Dt, X
OPEN CursorA
FETCH NEXT FROM CursorA INTO @Dt, @X, @Y, @newX
SET @tX = @X        -- initialize for change in X detection

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

-- a change in X?
IF (@tX != @X)
BEGIN
    -- change in X, update all prior X to their newX (which should all be the same)
    UPDATE #tmpA SET X = newX WHERE Dt = @tDt AND X = @tX
select 1 as debug, @tX as tX, @min_X as minX, @min_newX as minR, @X as X, @Y as Y, @newX as newX
    SET @tX = @X
END

IF (@newX != 0)
BEGIN
    -- newX for this X and Y already assigned, move on
    FETCH NEXT FROM CursorA INTO @Dt, @X, @Y, @newX
    CONTINUE
END

IF (@Dt != @tDt)
BEGIN
    -- date change
    SET @tDt = @Dt

    -- all for this first X are simply the same identifier
    UPDATE #tmpA SET newX = @X WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X = @X
select 2 as debug, @tX as tX, @min_X as minX, @min_newX as minR, @X as X, @Y as Y, @newX as newX
    FETCH NEXT FROM CursorA INTO @Dt, @X, @Y, @newX
    CONTINUE
END

-- still on same date
-- is there any duplicate Y already assigned a newX?
SELECT @min_X = MIN(X) FROM #tmpA
    WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X != @X AND Y = @Y AND newX != 0

IF @min_X IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

    -- there is a Y duplicate within this date
    -- find the earliest X which does not have a duplicate Y
    SELECT @min_newX = MIN(X) FROM #tmpA
        WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X != @X AND Y != @Y AND newX != 0
        AND X NOT IN (SELECT X FROM #tmpA
            WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X != @X AND Y = @Y AND newX != 0)

    IF @min_newX IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN

        -- is there an "earlier" X already assigned a newX?
        SELECT @min_X = MIN(newX) FROM #tmpA
            WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X = @X AND newX !=0

        IF @min_X IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN

            -- there is another X already assigned a newX
            IF @min_newX >= @min_X
            BEGIN
                -- set the other one to this one
                UPDATE #tmpA SET newX = @min_newX
                    WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X = @X AND newX = @min_X
                UPDATE #tmpA SET newX = @min_newX
                    WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X = @X AND Y = @Y
select 3 as debug, @tX as tX, @min_X as minX, @min_newX as minR, @X as X, @Y as Y, @newX as newX
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                UPDATE #tmpA SET newX = @min_X
                    WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X = @X AND Y = @Y
select 4 as debug, @tX as tX, @min_X as minX, @min_newX as minR, @X as X, @Y as Y, @newX as newX
            END

            FETCH NEXT FROM CursorA INTO @Dt, @X, @Y, @newX
            CONTINUE
        END

        -- 
        UPDATE #tmpA SET newX = @min_newX
            WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X = @X AND Y = @Y
select 5 as debug, @tX as tX, @min_X as minX, @min_newX as minR, @X as X, @Y as Y, @newX as newX
        FETCH NEXT FROM CursorA INTO @Dt, @X, @Y, @newX
        CONTINUE

    END

    -- no other X without a duplicate Y already assigned a newX so assign this entire X set to itself
    UPDATE #tmpA SET newX = @X WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X = @X
select 6 as debug, @tX as tX, @min_X as minX, @min_newX as minR, @X as X, @Y as Y, @newX as newX
    FETCH NEXT FROM CursorA INTO @Dt, @X, @Y, @newX
    CONTINUE
END

-- no other Y but it's possible that another newX for this X is set to something different
SELECT @min_newX = MIN(newX) FROM #tmpA
    WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X = @X AND Y != @Y AND newX != 0

-- also find the min X for this Y
SELECT @min_X = MIN(X) FROM #tmpA
    WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X != @X AND Y != @Y AND newX != 0

IF @min_newX IS NULL
BEGIN
    -- no other Y for this X is assigned so set it to the minimum X already found
    UPDATE #tmpA SET newX = @min_X
        WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X = @X AND Y = @Y
select 7 as debug, @tX as tX, @min_X as minX, @min_newX as minR, @X as X, @Y as Y, @newX as newX
    FETCH NEXT FROM CursorA INTO @Dt, @X, @Y, @newX
    CONTINUE
END

-- there is another of the same X with a newX
IF (@min_X = @min_newX OR @min_X > @min_newX OR @min_newX IS NULL)
BEGIN
    -- there is a different Y for this X which has already been assigned the same newX as this one should be
    -- or a later one was found
    UPDATE #tmpA SET newX = @min_X
        WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X = @X AND Y = @Y
select 8 as debug, @tX as tX, @min_X as minX, @min_newX as minR, @X as X, @Y as Y, @newX as newX
    FETCH NEXT FROM CursorA INTO @Dt, @X, @Y, @newX
    CONTINUE
END

UPDATE #tmpA SET newX = @min_newX
    WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X = @X AND Y = @Y
select 9 as debug, @tX as tX, @min_X as minX, @min_newX as minR, @X as X, @Y as Y, @newX as newX
FETCH NEXT FROM CursorA INTO @Dt, @X, @Y, @newX

END

-- gotta catch the last set
UPDATE #tmpA SET X = newX WHERE Dt = @Dt AND X = @tX

SELECT * FROM #tmpA
--  ORDER BY Dt, X, Y
CLOSE CursorA
DEALLOCATE CursorA
RETURN
```

Here is what the output should look like...

```
Dt                      X   Y   newX    origX
2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 1   2   1   1
2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 1   1   1   1
2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 1   5   1   2
2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 3   2   3   3
2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 3   3   3   3
2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 1   3   1   4
2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 3   5   3   5
2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 6   5   6   6
2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 6   2   6   7
2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 6   1   6   7
2012-06-02 00:00:00.000 1   2   1   1
2012-06-02 00:00:00.000 1   1   1   1
2012-06-02 00:00:00.000 1   5   1   2
2012-06-02 00:00:00.000 3   2   3   3
2012-06-02 00:00:00.000 3   3   3   3
2012-06-02 00:00:00.000 1   3   1   4
2012-06-02 00:00:00.000 3   5   3   5
2012-06-02 00:00:00.000 6   5   6   6
2012-06-02 00:00:00.000 7   7   7   7
2012-06-02 00:00:00.000 7   1   7   7
2012-06-02 00:00:00.000 7   5   7   7
```

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Why not just let y be totally unique, which is easy?

Comment: The details of why are too extensive for this forum but it has to do with healthcare labs data. There are default or core panels and customized ones. If the customized one contains elements of 3 core panels, it will display in 3 columns, all with the same date.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like this.  Paste this in after the inserts into the temp table

```
select * from 
(
select X, Y, origX, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY X ORDER BY x) newX
from #tmpA
)
results
```

Comment: In SQL it is always the goal to "describe what you want".  In programming languages the goal is to "describe how to do what you want".  You can apply programming constructs to sql, and it will work, but it will be sub-optimal.  Row number documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: Believe me, I tried that and several variations of it. None of them worked, including this one. You also forgot to take the date into account. Using only the first date in the sample data, the above produces incorrect results by assigning Y=5 to X=1 three times.

Comment: What about select * from
(
select dt, newX, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by X order by x) newY
from
(
 select * from 
 (
 select Dt, X, Y, origX, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Dt, X ORDER BY Dt, x) newX
 from #tmpA
 )
 results1
) results2
) results

Comment: Nope, still produced duplicate Ys for the same X and it changed some Y values. Seems like if there is an atomic solution (which I doubt exists because there are too many paths in the iterative method), it will have to at least include MIN and NOT IN.

Comment: I am sure there is one.  I just don't understand what you're doing, or why.  " If the customized one contains elements of 3 core panels, it will display in 3 columns, all with the same date"  Just don't see how this relates to rows.  Or why you have no pks/fks linking your data together.

Comment: Fair enough, it's not your responsibility to find one. I believe I have provided enough information to understand the problem, but granted, not why. There is a primary key but it is irrelevant to this problem; it identifies the specific result of a test. The X and Y columns are foreign keys. X is the panel identifier and Y identifies the specific test type, such as basophils, uric acid and urobili.

Comment: When results are entered for each of those three under separate core categories, such as hematology, misc. and urine analysis, for example, they display in three different columns in the custom category because they have three different panel or X  identifiers. If the X identifier is reassigned to be the same for all three, then they will display in a single column in the custom category, and will still display correctly in each of their original categories as entered.

Comment: The original developers should have allowed the user to first specify the date, then enter all results under the same panel. But no, the date is specified for each category even though all results are from the same test or panel. The application should be restructured to allow that, but alas, that's not how "business" works. Hope that makes more sense.